# How do I find what these breakers go to?

Tags: electrical, breaker-box

I recently mapped every appliance, receptacle, light fixture, switch to their respective breaker in the master 200A electrical panel.  When I was finished I ended up with 2 20A breakers that did not go to anything I could find.  The breakers were on when we bought the house.  I have since shut them off not knowing what they go to.

Is there any other way to trace them or should I just not worry about them and leave them shut off?

Comment: I should add I took the cover off the panel and each of the 2 unmapped breakers have a black wire going to them.

Comment: If they were larger I would suspect that they were for an electric range or electric dryer, where you have gas.  But 20A is too small for those.

Comment: Often 20amp breakers are for dedicated outlets in your kitchen

Comment: Might also be useful to clamp an ammeter/multimeter around the hot wire to these breakers to see if there is any load on them.  If load is non-zero then they are in use and doing something, if its zero its possible they are not in use, go nowhere, etc.

Answer (score 8):

Short of buying and using a tracer, I'd check for:

- appliances that were converted to another fuel source
- appliances that you aren't using currently (e.g. AC or sprinkler system in the winter)
- appliances that you may not notice aren't working, like sump pumps and radon fans
- check outdoors, detached structures, in crawl spaces, and attics that you may have missed when labeling the circuits
- check for outlets that may have been used to connect a generator

Lastly, if you turned off just these circuits to see what stopped working, do the reverse. Turn everything else off except the one circuit. It's entirely possible that someone bridged two circuits together somewhere.

The location in the panel may give you a clue. Similar appliances are often grouped near each other, and additions tend to be added to empty spaces at the bottom.

Comment: What is bridging circuits?  Is it safe?  Why would they do this?  Also, don't have any appliances that are not electric.  No sump pump, radon fan, nor sprinkler system (in my yard? ha!)

Comment: One to add to the list - alarm systems.  Most, but not all, give some clear indication of whether they have mains power or not.  Some (e.g. smoke alarms in my house) have both mains and battery power, and a rather subtle LED that goes off when they don't have mains. 20A is a lot for an alarm, but you couldn't rule it out on that alone.  Also +1 for turn everything else off. And I'd guess a tracer would be of limited use.

Comment: Bridging circuits is a mistake, but one that can easily happen when someone rewires a junction that contains two circuits. It can be a simple as a switched outlet where the tab wasn't removed on the replaced outlet. If this is the case, you'd see current on the hot wire coming off this breaker even when switched off.

Comment: @BMitch: I've sometimes thought there should be a standard convention for indicating which wires have a connection back to the panel and which don't; e.g. label "upstream" wires to be labeled with a small piece of yellow tape, and "downstream" with purple [picking colors I don't think are used for other purposes]. That would make dangerous wiring errors like bridging obvious (never connect yellow-tagged wires) and also help make clear many scenarios where power feeds out to, and returns from, a switch.

Answer (score 6):

It is always possible that the two extra breakers and circuits are spares that were wired in. Sometimes, particularly when some circuits are added after the initial building construction, it is cost effective to string extra wires from the electrical panel to a more centralized and easily accessible location.

The most obvious thing to find out where these two circuits connect is to suggest that you follow the two black wires from those circuit breakers to where they exit the breaker panel. Then continue to trace them to where they are routed through the framing of the building. This of course gets complicated fast when the wires are not visible and are covered over by wall and ceiling materials.

One clue that can be worth considering is if the two circuits are wired up with wiring that looks different from the rest of the installation. You may find for example that, if Romex was used, that the wire jacket is a different color or is stamped with a different label. You can then enter spaces such as attics, crawl spaces, unfinished garages or unfinished utility areas of the house to see if you can spot these particular wires being routed through that area.

Another thing to consider, especially if this house was built from a very standard plan, that it is possible that the extra circuits were installed at the time of original construction. They may have been to support some building option that ended up not being selected by the original owner. Some items like this could be wiring routed to near a fire place, wiring to lamp post locations out at the end of a driveway, wiring installed for a dishwasher when none was ever actually installed.

There are also circuit wiring tracer devices available that inject a signal into the wiring and than supposedly allow you to trace wires using a pickup probe that is near the wire. I have found that these do not work very well because the close proximity of all the wires in the main panel causes the signal to couple into many of the other wires as well. It is possible that a more expensive tracer may be more effective than the lower cost one that I have used.

Answer (score 0):

I have not yet figured out what circuit my smoke detectors are on after 3 years in this house. I had mapped out the entire box early on, but only recently thought of those. They MUST be on a shared circuit, because every breaker has some function attached to it. However, yours may be dedicated to those detectors.